# Proof that if $Ax=b$, then $x=A^{-1}b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say we have $Ax=b$ where $A$ is a matrix.

What is the proof that if we multiply both sides of equation with a matrix (inverse of $A$ in this case), then they are still equal?

Comment: If you multiply a matrix by another one, it doesn't matter if the first matrix is called $Ax$ or $b$, so long as equality holds.

Comment: In a sense, this is not an issue of linear algebra, but of logic. If $a=b$, then also $f(a)=f(b)$, simply because $a$ and $b$ are the same thing.

Comment: @mathse I looked at the problem from a different perspective and missed that simple logic. I would downvote myself. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the inverse exists, then it is a function.
Functions satisfy the property that if $x = y$, then $f(x) = f(y)$.
That is,
$$
A^{-1}(Ax) = A^{-1}(b).
$$

Comment: Does it mean, if A is not invertible, we cannot multiply both sides with a random matrix?

Comment: @khajvah You can *always* multiply both sides by *any* matrix.  But you cannot multiply by $A^{-1}$ if $A^{-1}$ does not exist, because if it does not exist then it cannot be a matrix!

Comment: It is worth to mention that if $x=y$ then $f(x)=f(y)$, but if one would like to prove that $x=y$ based on the validity of $f(x)=f(y)$, then $f$ should be one-to-one. E.g., $\alpha^2=\beta^2$ does not generally imply $\alpha=\beta$ for real $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as $f(x)=x^2$ is not one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $Ax = b$. Assume that $A$ is invertible so that $A^{-1}$ exists. Let $I$ represent the identity matrix. Then observe that:
\begin{align*}
x &= Ix &\text{by definition of the identity matrix} \\
&= (A^{-1}A)x &\text{by definition of inverses} \\
&= A^{-1}(Ax) &\text{by associativity} \\
&= A^{-1}b &\text{since $Ax = b$}
\end{align*}
as desired.